# Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, hsqldb

I use Spring Boot and HSQLDB and I can't connect to the database.
I always get an error "Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections" despite the fact that I'm using the latest version of the driver.

My application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:bank_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
        
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

My entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "banks")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bank {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "bank_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH},
            mappedBy = "bank")
    private List<Credit> credits = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH},
            mappedBy = "bank")
    private List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Client {


   @Id
   @Column(name = "credit_id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private UUID id;

   @Column(name = "telephone_number")
   private Long telephoneNumber;

   @Column(name = "email")
   private String email;

   @Column(name = "passport_number")
   private Long passportNumber;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Bank.class,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
   @JoinColumn(name = "bank_id")
   private Bank bank;

   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH},
           mappedBy = "client")
   private List<CreditOffer> creditOffers;


}


@Entity
@Table(name = "credits")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Credit {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "credit_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "credit_limit")
    private Long creditLimit;

    @Column(name = "credit_percent")
    private BigDecimal creditPercent;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Bank.class,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "bank_id")
    private Bank bank;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH},
            mappedBy = "credit")
    List<CreditOffer> creditOffers;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "credit_offer")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CreditOffer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "credit_offer_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Client.class,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Credit.class,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "credit_id")
    private Credit credit;

    @Column(name = "sum_of_credit")
    private BigDecimal sumOfCredit;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = PaymentSchedule.class,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "payment_schedule_id")
    private PaymentSchedule paymentSchedule;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_schedule")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PaymentSchedule {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "payment_schedule_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "date_of_payment")
    private Date dateOfPayment;

    @Column(name = "sum_of_payment")
    private BigDecimal sumOfPayment;

    @Column(name = "sum_of_principal")
    private BigDecimal sumOfPrincipal;

    @Column(name = "sum_of_percent")
    private BigDecimal sumOfPercent;


}
```

I output i get:

```
2022-01-18 03:02:59.911  INFO 10856 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2022-01-18 03:02:59.913  INFO 10856 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-01-18 03:02:59.931  INFO 10856 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists banks CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists clients CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists credit_offer CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists credits CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists payment_schedule CASCADE 
Hibernate: create table banks (bank_id binary(255) not null, primary key (bank_id))
Hibernate: create table clients (credit_id binary(255) not null, email varchar(255), passport_number bigint, telephone_number bigint, bank_id binary(255), primary key (credit_id))
Hibernate: create table credit_offer (credit_offer_id binary(255) not null, sum_of_credit numeric(19,2), client_id binary(255), credit_id binary(255), payment_schedule_id binary(255), primary key (credit_offer_id))
Hibernate: create table credits (credit_id binary(255) not null, credit_limit bigint, credit_percent numeric(19,2), bank_id binary(255), primary key (credit_id))
Hibernate: create table payment_schedule (payment_schedule_id binary(255) not null, date_of_payment timestamp, sum_of_payment numeric(19,2), sum_of_percent numeric(19,2), sum_of_principal numeric(19,2), primary key (payment_schedule_id))
Hibernate: alter table clients add constraint FKj0ik8mxsdhpqul7b0narc59og foreign key (bank_id) references banks
Hibernate: alter table credit_offer add constraint FKkarou343ffyichgtfy8yipelm foreign key (client_id) references clients
Hibernate: alter table credit_offer add constraint FK69n239vuy0ehdy1dq3bsd2ea9 foreign key (credit_id) references credits
Hibernate: alter table credit_offer add constraint FKdgpc16jjpyltxelv6qh90vo3l foreign key (payment_schedule_id) references payment_schedule
Hibernate: alter table credits add constraint FKt3c6cd1lq2lsiclu6bh2pux2y foreign key (bank_id) references banks
```

That is, tables are created, but it is not clear where and it is not clear why I do not see any changes in the database, not even connections to it

Dependencies in pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: That _Driver does not support..._ message is an INFO message (not an error), and may be related to using an in-memory database (based on the `spring.datasource.url` value).

Comment: Ok, how I can get access to my tables? Intellij IDEA plugin cannot connect to DB